# Salesforce LWC - error message when using querySelector on a datalist element

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lwc

I'm writing a lightning web component in which I have to assign a `<datalist>` element to one of my `<input>` elements' `list` property, in order to bind them.

For some reason, this JS line:

```
const streetsListId = this.template.querySelector('streetdatalist').id;
```

Throws this JS error message:

> Cannot read property 'id' of null

**Web component HTML:**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <input  id="inputstreet"
                name="inputstreet"
                type="text"
                list="streetdatalist"
                label="Search"
                onkeydown={onStreetChange}
                onblur={onStreetChange} />

        <datalist id="streetdatalist">
             <template for:each={streets} for:item='street'>
                 <option key={city.cityCode}>{city.cityName}</option>
             </template>
        </datalist>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Web component JS:**

```
renderedCallback() {
    if (this.initialized) {
        return;
    }
    this.initialized = true;

    const streetsListId = this.template.querySelector('streetdatalist').id;
    this.template.querySelector('inputstreet').setAttribute('list', streetsListId);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by changing the querySelector with `'[data-id=`:

```
const citiesListId = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="streetdatalist"]').id;
```